# PHP + MySQL - While Loop not

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to PHP + MySQL so, please pardon my confusion —
I don't understand why my code won't loop through the `'underground_name'` column and echo all the rows?

Here's my code...

```
<?php
    include("../includes/header.php");
    require('../../mysqli_connect.php');
    include("../functions/filter_time.php");

    // query the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projects_underground, underground, projects
            LEFT JOIN river ON projects.river_id=river.river_id 
            LEFT JOIN dlr ON projects.dlr_id=dlr.dlr_id 
            LEFT JOIN overground ON projects.overground_id=overground.overground_id 
            LEFT JOIN natrail ON projects.natrail_id=natrail.natrail_id 
            LEFT JOIN tram ON projects.tram_id=tram.tram_id

            WHERE 
            projects_underground.underground_fk = underground.underground_id AND
            projects_underground.projects_fk = projects.projects_id AND
            name = 'Imperial War Museum'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); // put queried result into variable
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // put that into seperate arrays called $row
    $ug = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    while ($ug = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $ug['underground_name'];
    }
?>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Try running your query on the SQL console, and check what results you get.
2. Try dumping the `$ug` array to see if the output is being fetched.
3. You're calling `mysqli_fetch_*()` thrice, once while initializing `$row`, once while initializing `$ug`, and once more in the while loop. This will miss the first two rows - and consequently, if you have only two rows in the query result, no output would be printed.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // Fetches first result row off the stack 
$ug = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  // Fetches second result row

while ($ug = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // Fetches third row
     // Starts printing from the third row (if there is any)
     echo $ug['underground_name'];
}
```

Comment: 1. SQL Query - `SELECT underground_name FROM projects_underground, projects, underground WHERE projects_underground.underground_fk = underground.underground_id AND projects_underground.projects_fk = projects.projects_id AND projects_id = 5`  creates the expected result in PHPmyAdmin —  2. — When I `(var_dump($row['underground_name'])` I only get the 1st row of results? Very confused...? –

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc` functions return an individual row from the result. Each subsequent call to one of those would return the next row in the result (or `NULL` if there are no more rows left). Hence, `$row` in your current code would contain the 1st row, `$ug` would contain the second row (before the while loop), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that when you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` or `mysqli_fetch_array($result);` that you are fetching a row off the result stack. So before you ever reach the `while` statement you've already gotten two rows off. So if your query returned three results, you'd only show one in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Machavity.

Comment: `SELECT underground_name FROM projects_underground, projects, underground WHERE projects_underground.underground_fk = underground.underground_id AND projects_underground.projects_fk = projects.projects_id AND projects_id = 5
` creates the expected result in PHPmyAdmin — but when I `(var_dump($row['underground_name'])` I only get the 1st row of results? Very confused...?

Comment: @CallMePhilip Remember that these functions only return one row at a time. If you want an array of arrays you will have to build your own loop that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following to see how many rows are being returned:

echo $result->num_rows().' rows have been returned.'.PHP_EOL;

Here's an update to your code that I think should do the trick (by removing the earlier calls to fetch_assoc and fetch_array and adding some basic checking that any rows have been returned):

```
<?php
include("../includes/header.php");
require('../../mysqli_connect.php');
include("../functions/filter_time.php");

// query the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM projects_underground, underground, projects
        LEFT JOIN river ON projects.river_id=river.river_id 
        LEFT JOIN dlr ON projects.dlr_id=dlr.dlr_id 
        LEFT JOIN overground ON projects.overground_id=overground.overground_id 
        LEFT JOIN natrail ON projects.natrail_id=natrail.natrail_id 
        LEFT JOIN tram ON projects.tram_id=tram.tram_id

        WHERE 
        projects_underground.underground_fk = underground.underground_id AND
        projects_underground.projects_fk = projects.projects_id AND
        name = 'Imperial War Museum'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); // put queried result into variable

if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows() > 0) {

    // This line is just for testing, delete from real code
    echo $result->num_rows().' rows have been returned.'.PHP_EOL;

    while ($ug = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $ug['underground_name'];
    }
} else {
    // Do something if no results were returned
}
?>
```